# Can I call a Jenkins job from Udeploy?

Tags: jenkins, udeploy

I have a different kind of requirement wherein I want a Jenkins job to trigger automatically once an artifact is deployed to udeploy. I know this is reverse of what is usually done (Jenkins job calling udeploy).

I wanted to know if there is any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

We use CURL and trigger the Jenkins job, in the component configuration there is an option to "Run Process after a Version is Created", hope this helps